Which episode of Fresh Prince did Uncle Philip hit Will?
This gif came up in my facebook feed earlier today. While entertaining, it did get myself and others wondering:

What episode of The Fresh Prince of Bel-air was this scene in?
outside of the gif, how often did Uncle Phil hit his kids/ward? 
(As I recall he never did, but the gif suggests otherwise)



This is from Season 3, Episode 15, "Robbing the Banks". Uncle Phil slaps Will for trying to flirt with the court stenographer, and for goofing off in general. 

From what I can remember, I don't think Uncle Phil hits/slaps Will much at all. On the other hand, I do remember Vivian slapping Will several times, often on the back on the head. 
